# Change the state based on the previous state with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was watching a tutorial and in one moment he does this:

```
export default function Editor(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={`container ${open ? "" : "collapsed"}`}>
       <button onClick={() => setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}>O/C</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is: why this

```
<button onClick={() => setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}>O/C</button>
```

and not

```
<button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>O/C</button>
```

I tried both and they seem to work.

Comment: You can read about it in the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates . In your example, it wouldn't make any difference, but sometimes it is not the same since the variable you get as 'prevState' will always contain the latest state and is more reliable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `open` may not actually be the previous state. In your code it is, but in more complicated components there may be multiple pieces of code that set state. If these happen at around the same time, react may batch them up and apply them all at once.

Usually, these pieces of code will be in separate parts of the component and thus it's hard to spot. But for demonstration purposes, i'll put them right next to eachother:

```
onClick={() => {
  setOpen(!open)
  setOpen(!open)
})
```

With the above code, we ask react to set the state to `false`, and then we ask react to set the state to `false` again. End result is that it's false. That's probably not what's intended: if we toggle the state twice, it's probably because we want it to go back to the original state.

```
onClick={() => {
  setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)
  setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)
})
```

This code will set it to `false`, and then set it to `true`. Each function gets passed in the most recent value, even if that value is different than the value of `open` in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update the state which depends on the previous state then you need to call the setState like `<button onClick={() => setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}>O/C</button>`. This is the important rule of how you set the state.